# Compute triple integral $ \iiint\limits_D \sin(xy) - \sin(xz) + \sin(yz) \, dx \, dy \, dz $

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $D = \{ (x,y,z): 1 \leq x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 4 \}$ then compute

$$
\iiint\limits_D \sin(xy) - \sin(xz) + \sin(yz) \, dx \, dy \, dz
$$

I tried to use spherical coordinates but then the integrand becomes super ugly if I try to use cartesian coordinates then the domain gets ugly, it looks like there must be something better to do here.

Comment: Think to change $ x $ in $-x$.

Comment: For this question, I would recommend using Cartesian coordinates and dealing with the domain being a bit ugly.  You can make it somewhat nicer by breaking the integral up into the sphere with radius 2 - sphere with radius 1, rather than trying to integrate over a non-uniform shape.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity So you want to evaluate an integral that's obviously $0$ as the difference of two integrals obviously being $0$, do I get that right?

Comment: Please note $\sin(-xy) = -\sin(xy)$ and there is absolute symmetry. Two quadrants are positive and two are negative. Same is true for others. Save some work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: concentric spheres]

$$\int\limits_{x=-2}^2 \int\limits_{y = -\sqrt{4 - x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}} \int\limits_{z= -\sqrt{4 - x^2 - y^2}}^{\sqrt{4 - x^2 - y^2}} \left( \sin (x y) - \sin (x z) + \sin (y z) \right) dx\ dy\ dz - \\ \int\limits_{x=-1}^1 \int\limits_{y = -\sqrt{1 - x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \int\limits_{z=-\sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2}}^{\sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2}} \left( \sin (x y) - \sin (x z) + \sin (y z)\right) dx\ dy\ dz \\ = 0 - 0 = 0$$

Answer (score 2):

Due to symmetry

$$
\iiint\limits_D \sin(xy)\, dx \, dy \, dz
= \iiint\limits_D \sin(xz) dx \, dy \, dz
= \iiint\limits_D \sin(yz) \, dx \, dy \, dz
$$
Then
$$\iiint\limits_D \sin(xy) - \sin(xz) + \sin(yz) \, dx \, dy \, dz
= \iiint\limits_D \sin(xy)\, dx \, dy \, dz=0
$$
which vanishes per the symmetry  with respect to $z$